# Error initializing Highcharts modules: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I was trying to import the volume-by-price,indicators and exporting modules from highchart in my angular application. In my typescript file I have used this in imports:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import indicators from 'highcharts/indicators/indicators';
import volumeByPrice from 'highcharts/indicators/volume-by-price';
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
```

and in my ngnInit() function in the typescript file, I have used:

```
    HC_exporting(Highcharts);
    indicators(Highcharts);
    volumeByPrice(Highcharts);
```

But I'm still facing the error:- Error initializing Highcharts modules: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty').
Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Could you provide a demo reproducing this problem? It's a bit surprising as with the code you shared everything should work fine. Here's an example demo importing indicators from HighStock: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-with-indicators?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts